# Eclipse RCP using e4 tools

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, e4

How can I minimize or maximize the views in a window in an RCP application using e4 tools. I have 2 views one is a table and another is a welcome page, I am trying to increase the width of my table view so that it takes more than half of the window space. I am customizing the UI using the Application.e4xmi found in the e4 tools? I tried using the container space but it does not work? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that your model looks something like this:

```
Perspective (or Window)
    PartSashContainer
        Part Stack
            Part (Welcome)
        Part Stack
            Part (Table)
```

You can use the Attribute "Container Data" on each of the PartStack Elements in your Model.

For example you can have the Table-Part use 70% of the available space:

```
Perspective (or Window)
    PartSashContainer
        Part Stack [container data=30]
            Part [id=welcome]
        Part Stack [container data=70]
            Part [id=table]
```

Comment: Hi keimel. Actually my model is like i have 2 PartSash containers with first one containing the welcome view and the other one the table. I can change the container data but that doesnt change the width of the table view?

Comment: Imho it only makes sense to use a PartSash, when the sash has at least 2 children. Otherwise, where is the point? Try my suggestion above and see how that works for you. You can  also leave out the PartStack elements, but I think that will also remove the title of the Part.